# NSNumber returning different value than the original int

Tags: objective-c

I am quite new to objective-c and I am trying to convert an int into a NSNumber so that I can save it into Core-Data.

I've the following piece of code (index is an NSInteger)

```
- (void) associateOrNotToARoutine:(NSString*)exerciseName associate:(BOOL)associate index:(NSInteger)index

NSLog(@"number w index %d, %d",[NSNumber numberWithInteger:index],index);
```

and it returns

```
number w index 170413600, 2
```

I need an int of 2 to be translated into a number 2 along with all other numbers to be translated into the correct number... Could anyone tell me why i am getting this convertion? I tried reading on `NSNumber` manual but i found nothing

Comment: the first is the the _pointer_ of the `NSNumber`, not the value which it has, try that instead: `[[NSNumber numberWithInteger:index] integerValue]`, and you will get the same integer as the `index` is.

Comment: BTW - Xcode and the compiler should be giving you some sort of warning telling you that `%d` isn't appropriate for the `NSNumber` argument.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
NSLog(@"number w index %@, %d",[NSNumber numberWithInteger:index],index);
                       ^^
```

The `%@` format specifier will call the `[NSNumber description]` method, which should return the value you are after.  Your original code will return the address of the `NSNumber` object, not its content.

Answer (score 4):

*Even though this question has already been answered, I thought I'd flesh out a longer answer for future readers in general:*

**What's happening?**
`%d` is a [C format string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string) used to indicate one of the passed parameters is an integer (`int`) ivar value.  Much like `%f` is used for `float` values.

`[NSNumber numberWithInteger:index]` returns a pointer to an NSNumber instance.  If you use `%d`, NSLog thinks you're passing it an integer when, in fact, you're passing a pointer.  So the pointer value (a memory address) is printed.

**What's `%@`?**
As mentioned by trojanfoe: `%@` tells `NSLog()` that you are passing an object.  In that case, NSLog asks the object to describe itself using a string… it calls the [`description`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/description) method.

**Specific answer**
For this specific question, there are multiple ways.  The two main one being:

- `NSLog(@"number w index %@, %d", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:index], index);`
- `NSLog(@"number w index %d, %d", [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:index] intValue], index);`

**Extra goodness**
When using `%@`, the passed object can be anything that responds to `description`, essentially any descendant of NSObject.  Also, if you're creating your own classes, it's a good idea to overload `description` to return a more meaningful string than the default NSObject implementation.

```
// Try using it with NSArray or NSDictionary and see how each describe themselves.
NSLog(@"the array description: %@", myArray);
NSLog(@"the dictionary description: %@", myDictionary);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use,

```
[[NSNumber numberWithInteger:index] intValue]
```

to get the integer value, the NSNumber, is holding